# Corrupted text file recovery (Win7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, notepad++

I'm having some difficulties in recovering the contents of a .txt file. While writing to a text file, on a Win7 x64 virtual machine, the host machine crashed. After rebooting, I noticed that the file's contents are no longer visible in notepad. Using notepad++, however, reveals that all content has been overwritten with NULL values and the file's size remained the same. Here is a snapshot of notepad++.

[image: Corrupted file]

Are there any means of recovery since it was stored on a virtual drive(I'm using vmware)?

Comment: No; the file contents are gone. Notepad++ introduce a feature to prevent problems like this, it has a basic, file backup system that was introduced in the most recent major version.  The file was never saved to the vhdd, which means, the data never existed on the actuall hdd.

Comment: Windows Pervious Versions? Backup? Previous VM Snapshot?  Otherwise, nope.

Comment: Sadly, none of those methods are applicable at this point.